# Scala: Read data from MANIFEST.MF

Tags: scala

I'm building my Java/Scala project using `maven-assembly-plugin`,
I have a function in my project that prints my version number and I want to take it from MANIFEST.MF which is in the META-INF directory.

I found solutions for Java code but not for scala, the only thing I could find is [scala.reflect.Manifest](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest) but I couldn't understand if it is relevant to my case.

Comment: `scala.reflect.Manifest` is a different beast. You should convert the Java solution to Scala, or better yet, just use the Java version.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use java here, how can I convert java code to Scala?

Comment: Manually, though the IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin [might help](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5482480).